# setting custom delegate in custom view from nib file

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nib

I have a custom view that loads from a nib file. This view has a custom delegate, I set the delegate to my main view controller but then at some point the delegate gets set to nil again. 
here is I add the custom view to my view controller

```
  @IBAction func newGoalButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let newGoalView = AddGoalView(frame: self.view.frame)
    newGoalView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(newGoalView)
    newGoalView.present()
}
```

Here is how I load the nib file in my custom view init method

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:CGRect(x: frame.origin.x + 10, y: frame.height, width: frame.width - 20, height: frame.height / 3))
        self.addSubview(self.instanceFromNib())
}


private func instanceFromNib() -> AddGoalView {
    return UINib(nibName: "AddGoalView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! AddGoalView
}
```

and this is how I declare my protocol

```
    protocol NewGoalCreatedDelegate {
       func newGoalCreated(with proteinGoal:Int16, isCurrent:Bool)}
```

I set the files owner of my nib file to my custom class "AddGoalView", and also the view custom class to "AddGoalView". I also tried one or the other but no luck.

The delegate isnt nil until after my present method.

```
internal func present() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.center = self.superview!.center
    }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
        print(self.delegate!)
    })
    print(self.delegate!)
}
```

After that the delegate is nil, I know it is something related to how Im using my nib file but I dont know what it is.

Comment: I think you got confused in *Swing* vs *Swift* (already fixed)

Comment: Does your view controller properly conform to the delegate? i.e. `class ViewController: UIViewController, NewGoalCreatedDelegate { }`?

Comment: yess! otherwise I wont be able to set self as the property delegate:NewGoalCreatedDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to link the outlets in the file's owner, to the views of my xib.file [image]

.